# @TestSecurity tests no longer succeeding with custom HttpAuthenticationMechanism

Tags: quarkus

When adding a custom HttpAuthenticationMechanism, the @TestSecurity annotation does no longer work.

1. setup a project with SmallRye JWT authentication as described in https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jwt
2. create a @QuarkusTest test with test methods annotated with @TestSecurity(user = "user"), check for status code 200
3. run the test, they succeed, status code is 200
4. add a custom HttpAuthenticationMechanism without any custom logic, just forwarding the call (see below, documented in https://quarkus.io/guides/security-customization#dealing-with-more-than-one-http-auth-mechanisms)
5. tests no longer succeed, because returned result is 401

```
@Alternative
@Priority(1)
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyHttpAuthenticationMechanism implements HttpAuthenticationMechanism {

    @Inject
     JWTAuthMechanism jwt;
    
    @Override
    public Uni<SecurityIdentity> authenticate(RoutingContext context, IdentityProviderManager identityProviderManager) {
        return jwt.authenticate(context, identityProviderManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Uni<ChallengeData> getChallenge(RoutingContext context) {
        return jwt.getChallenge(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<? extends AuthenticationRequest>> getCredentialTypes() {
        return jwt.getCredentialTypes();
    }

    @Override
    public Uni<HttpCredentialTransport> getCredentialTransport(RoutingContext context) {
        return jwt.getCredentialTransport(context);
    }
}
```

How can I make the tests suceed again?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following class under `src/test/java` seems to be working.

```
@Alternative
@Priority(1)
@ApplicationScoped
public class TestHttpAuthenticationMechanism extends io.quarkus.test.security.TestHttpAuthenticationMechanism {
}
```

I assume the `io.quarkus.test.security.TestHttpAuthenticationMechanism` is not used in tests due the `@Alternative` and `@Priority` attributes on `MyHttpAuthenticationMechanism`. So setting these attributes on a subclass of `io.quarkus.test.security.TestHttpAuthenticationMechanism` makes this test mechanism being used again.